# Extending ValidationSummary in HTMLHelper to alter HTML output

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper

I have written my own ValidationSummary so I could change the output of the ValidationSummary however whenever I submit the form no warning messages are appearing.

I then added a normal ValidationSummary on the same view with my new ValidationSummary and when the page is initially requested the output is exactly the same.  As soon as the submit button is pressed the normal one works and outputs error messages but mine doesn't.

It doesnt seem to do a post back to the server so am I missing something?

```
 public static MvcHtmlString MyValidationSummary(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, bool excludePropertyErrors, string message, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
        {
            //<div class="validation-summary-errors" data-valmsg-summary="true"><ul><li>The User name field is required.</li><li>The Password field is required.</li></ul></div>

            /*
             * <div class="alert-wrapper error">
                    <div class="alert-text">
                        This is an error alert!
                        <a href="#" class="close">Close</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
             * 
             */
            if (htmlHelper == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("htmlHelper");
            }

            FormContext formContext = htmlHelper.ViewContext.FormContext;
            if (htmlHelper.ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (formContext == null)
                {  // No client side validation
                    return null;
                }
                // TODO: This isn't really about unobtrusive; can we fix up non-unobtrusive to get rid of this, too?
                if (htmlHelper.ViewContext.UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled && excludePropertyErrors)
                {  // No client-side updates
                    return null;
                }
            }

            string messageSpan;
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
            {
                TagBuilder spanTag = new TagBuilder("span");
                spanTag.SetInnerText(message);
                messageSpan = spanTag.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal) + Environment.NewLine;
            }
            else
            {
                messageSpan = null;
            }

            StringBuilder htmlSummary = new StringBuilder();
            //TagBuilder unorderedList = new TagBuilder("ul");

            IEnumerable<ModelState> modelStates = null;

            if (excludePropertyErrors)
            {
                ModelState ms;
                htmlHelper.ViewData.ModelState.TryGetValue(htmlHelper.ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix, out ms);
                if (ms != null)
                {
                    modelStates = new ModelState[] { ms };
                }
            }
            else
            {
                modelStates = htmlHelper.ViewData.ModelState.Values;
            }

            if (modelStates != null)
            {
                foreach (ModelState modelState in modelStates)
                {
                    foreach (ModelError modelError in modelState.Errors)
                    {
                        string errorText = GetUserErrorMessageOrDefault(htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext, modelError, null /* modelState */);
                        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(errorText))
                        {
                            //TagBuilder listItem = new TagBuilder("li");
                            //listItem.SetInnerText(errorText);
                            htmlSummary.AppendLine(errorText);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if (htmlSummary.Length == 0)
            {
                htmlSummary.AppendLine(_hiddenListItem);
            }

            //unorderedList.InnerHtml = htmlSummary.ToString();

            TagBuilder divBuilder = new TagBuilder("div");
            divBuilder.MergeAttributes(htmlAttributes);
            divBuilder.AddCssClass((htmlHelper.ViewData.ModelState.IsValid) ? HtmlHelper.ValidationSummaryValidCssClassName : HtmlHelper.ValidationSummaryCssClassName);

            TagBuilder innerDivBuilder = new TagBuilder("div");
            innerDivBuilder.AddCssClass("alert-text");

            TagBuilder closeBuilder = new TagBuilder("a");
            closeBuilder.AddCssClass("close");
            closeBuilder.Attributes.Add("href", "#");

            divBuilder.InnerHtml = innerDivBuilder.InnerHtml + messageSpan + htmlSummary.ToString() + closeBuilder.InnerHtml; 

            if (formContext != null)
            {
                if (htmlHelper.ViewContext.UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled)
                {
                    if (!excludePropertyErrors)
                    {  // Only put errors in the validation summary if they're supposed to be included there
                        divBuilder.MergeAttribute("data-valmsg-summary", "true");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // client val summaries need an ID
                    divBuilder.GenerateId("validationSummary");
                    formContext.ValidationSummaryId = divBuilder.Attributes["id"];
                    formContext.ReplaceValidationSummary = !excludePropertyErrors;
                }
            }

            return new MvcHtmlString(divBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
            //return divBuilder.ToMvcHtmlString(TagRenderMode.Normal);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that you have to have a `<ul>` in your ValidationSummary and the javascript then appends `<li>` to the unorderelist client side so essentially you cannot change the HTML in ValidationSummary if you want it to work client side without then changing the validation javascript as well.